# discrete fourier transform in Matlab - theoretical confusion

Tags: matlab, fft, fourier-transform, dft

I have a periodic term $V(x) = \sum_K  \exp(iKx) V_K$ where $K =2\pi n/a$ where $a$ is the periodicity of the term and $n =0,1,2,3....$

Now I want to find the Fourier coefficient $V_K$ corresponding to a particular $K$. Suppose I have a vector for $V(x)$ having $10000$ points for $x = 0,0.01a,0.02a,...a,1.01a,....2a....100a$ such that the size of my lattice is $100a$.

FFT on this vector gives $10000$ Fourier coefficients. The $K$ values corresponding to these Fourier coefficients are $2\pi n/(10000*0.01a)$ with $n=0,1,2,3,...9999$. But my $K$ had the form $2\pi n/a$ due to the periodicity of the lattice.

What am I missing ?

Comment: MATLAB doesn't do indices less than 1.  anyway, i cannot decode the question.

Comment: read this for clarity http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/100923/confusion-in-discrete-transform-to-solve-kronig-penney-matrix-equation-in-fourie

Comment: first of all, LaTeX equation markup works just as well here as it does at the physics se.  second of all, your "clarity" post is no better, except it uses LaTeX markup.  make sure you express your summations with integer indices and make clear what the independent variable is (is it $x$?  then call it "$V(x)$".)  usually once the math is cleaned up and the question is made explicit, answers become clear.

Comment: made the changes as you mentioned, at the physics.se

Comment: This topic was also in addition to the phyisics site already extensively discussed at the duplicate (http://stackoverflow.com/q/22026363/3088138)